# Square Number Problem

Tags: square-numbers

If one is given a set of digits, such as 3352, is there a simple way of finding the square numbers closest to 0 that would begin with the given digits?

Comment: By "square numbers" do you mean that $n$ is a square number iff $\exists k$ such that $k^2 = n$?

Comment: So for example if your initial number is $3$, then the answer would be $36$?

Comment: Yes I mean the square root of n is an integer

Comment: If you try taking the square root of 3352 and 33520 and using the first few digits rounded up or down you come up with $579^2=335241$ and $1831^2=3352561$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\sqrt{3352}=57.89645930452\ldots$$
so that our first guesses would be $58^2$, $579^2$, $5790^2$, $57897^2$, $578965^2$ and so on as smallest squares above $3352$, $335200$, $33520000$, etc. Note that we simply cut off the expansion of the square root and rounded the last digit *up* to arrive at this sequence. This left out half the allowed powers of ten, so we also look at 
$$\sqrt{10\cdot 3352}= 183.084679861\ldots$$
and thus interlace the sequence above with $184^2$, $1831^2$, $18309^2$, etc. 
The first to give the correct leading digis will be our result.

In fact, we need not need to make so many tries if we compute 
$$\sqrt{3353+1}=57.9050947672\ldots $$
and 
$$\sqrt{10\cdot 2253+1}= 183.0874108\ldots$$
as well: The latter agrees with $\sqrt{10\cdot 3352}$ for the first two decimals, hence that branch need not be checked until we want to try the third decimal. On the other hand, alreday the first decimal of $57.9\ldots$ exceed that of $57.8\ldots$, so that we know that already working with the first decimal will help us. Thus $579^2=335241$ is the smallest perfect square starting with digits $3352$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Suppose $n$ is a natural number with $$n^2 = \underbrace{3352\ldots}_{x \text{ digits}}$$ Then $$0.3352 \times 10^x \le n^2 < 0.3353 \times 10^x$$ or $$3352 \times 10^{x-4} \le n^2 < 3353 \times 10^{x-4}.$$ If $x$ is even, put $x = 2k$ for a natural number $k$ and we'll see $$3352 \times 10^{2k- 4} \le n^2 < 3353 \times 10^{2k-4}$$ so $$\sqrt{3352} \times 10^{k-2} \le n < \sqrt{3353} \times 10^{k-2}$$ or $$57.896\ldots \times 10^{k-2} \le n <57.905\ldots \times 10^{k-2}.$$ If you want the smallest $n$, you want to take $k$ as small as possible. If you take $k = 2$, there will be no natural numbers $n$ which satisfy the inequality, so you need to take $k = 3$ in which case $n = 579$ works.

If $x$ is odd, then $x = 2k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$ and we have $$3352 \times 10^{2k-3} \le n^2 < 3353 \times 10^{2k-3}$$ or $$33520 \times 10^{2k-2} \le n^2 < 33530 \times 10^{2k-2}$$ so $$183.084\ldots \times 10^{k-1} \le n < 183.111\ldots \times 10^{k-1}.$$ Again, taking $k$ as small as possible, we will find $k=1$ doesn't work, but $k=2$ yields a solution $n = 1831$.

Thus the smallest $n$ such that $n^2$ begins with $3352$ is $n = 579$.

Comment: No, the cases would just flip. If it was a five digit integer, the case that $x$ is even would require multiplying both sides by 10, like I did above in the case that $x$ is odd.

Comment: Thanks. Very well explained